# RegEx -- Parsing strings in-between ${ }s but NOT '${ }'s

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression that will extract `_A_`, `12345`, `Non_Literal_Left`, and `Non_Literal_Right` from the following string:

```
... ${_A_}, ${12345}, '${Literal}' $yada yada'$[]' '${Non_Literal_Left} ${Non_Literal_Right}'
```

The closest I have been able to get is everything less the single quote restriction for literals:

```
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}").matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Which results in everything I want plus `Literal`, which I do not want to match.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a joy.

Something tells me a RegEx expression would have been a little cleaner.

```
/**
 * Utility class for parsing record field parameters in properties.
 *
 * @author Ryan
 *
 */
public static class PropertyParser {

    /**
     * Stores the results of parsing a property.
     *
     * @author Ryan
     *
     */
    public static class ParsedParameters {

        private final Set<String> literals;
        private final Set<String> parameters;

        private ParsedParameters() {
            this.parameters = new HashSet<String>();
            this.literals = new HashSet<String>();
        }

        /**
         * Adds a literal property value to this object.
         *
         * @param string The literal property value to add to this object.
         */
        private void addLiteral(String string) {
            this.literals.add(string);
        }

        /**
         * Adds a parameter name to this object.
         *
         * @param string The parameter name to add to this object.
         */
        private void addParameter(String string) {
            this.parameters.add(string);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the set of literals stored in this object.
         * 
         * @return The set of literals stored in this object.
         */
        public Set<String> getLiterals() {
            return this.literals;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the set of parameters stored in this object.
         *
         * @return The set of parameters stored in this object.
         */
        public Set<String> getParameters() {
            return this.parameters;
        }
    }

    private static final String BAD_FIELD_CHAR =
            "Illegal character detected for field parameter: %c";

    /**
     * Extracts placeholder field name parameters from the input string.
     * <p>
     * Single quotes can be used to avoid the parser interpreting the ${...}
     * as a field parameter.
     * <p>
     * For example, the parser would not detect any field parameters in the following string:
     * <p>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;#!/bin/bash<br>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;# Echos the first argument<br>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;echo '${1}'<br>
     * <p>
     * The {@link #PropertySubstitutor()} is responsible for removing the single quotes
     * surrounding the parameter when substituting the actual property value(s).
     * <p>
     * <b>Nested Parameters</b>
     * <p>
     * This parser itself will only parse the inner-most parameter or literal.
     * <p>
     * For example, ${Some${Value}} would actually be treated as a legal string, with
     * 'Value' as the only field parameter extracted.  During runtime substitution,
     * this would result in ${Somebody} if the record value for the field "Value" was "body".
     * <p>
     * Theoretically, this parser could then be ran again to extract this generated parameter.
     *
     * @param string The property to parse for field parameters.
     * @return An object containing the parsed parameters and literal values.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the property contains parameter syntax
     *         (i.e. ${text}) but contains illegal characters for the field.
     *         <p>
     *         Allowed characters for field names are alpha-numeric and underscores.
     */
    public static ParsedParameters parseParametersAndLiterals(String string)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if ((string == null) || string.isEmpty()) {
            return new ParsedParameters();
        }
        ParsedParameters result = new ParsedParameters();
        StringBuffer param = null;
        Character badChar = null;
        char c;
        char p = '^';
        boolean close = false;
        boolean lQuote = false;
        boolean open = false;
        int l = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            c = string.charAt(i);
            if (!lQuote && (p == '\'') && (c == '$')) {
                lQuote = true;
            } else if ((p == '$') && (c == '{')) {
                param = new StringBuffer();
                open = true;
                badChar = null;
            } else if (open
                    && (((c == '}') && (!lQuote || ((1 + i) == l))) || (lQuote && (p == '}')))) {
                open = false;
                close = true;
            } else if (open) {
                boolean validCharacter = Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) || (c == '_');
                if (validCharacter || (lQuote && (c != '}'))) {
                    param.append(c);
                }
                if (!validCharacter && (c != '}')) {
                    badChar = c;
                }
            }
            if (close) {
                if ((badChar != null) && !(lQuote && (p == '}') && (c == '\''))) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(BAD_FIELD_CHAR, badChar));
                } else if (c != '\'') {
                    if (param.length() > 0) {
                        result.addParameter(param.toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    result.addLiteral(param.toString());
                }
                lQuote = false;
                close = false;
                badChar = null;
            }
            p = c;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And tests, of course.

```
public class TestPropertyParser {

    private Set<String> literals;
    private Set<String> params;

    private void assertLiteralsContains(String string) {
        assertTrue(this.literals.contains(string));
    }

    private void assertParamsContains(String string) {
        assertTrue(this.params.contains(string));
    }

    private void assertResultSizes(Integer paramSize, Integer literalSize) {
        if (paramSize != null) {
            assertNotNull(this.params);
            assertEquals((int) paramSize, this.params.size());
        } else {
            assertNull(this.params);
        }
        if (literalSize != null) {
            assertNotNull(this.literals);
            assertEquals((int) literalSize, this.literals.size());
        } else {
            assertNull(this.literals);
        }
    }

    private void parseAndSet(String stringToParse) {
        ParsedParameters result = PropertyParser.parseParametersAndLiterals(stringToParse);
        this.literals = result.getLiterals();
        this.params = result.getParameters();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.params = new HashSet<String>();
        this.literals = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testParserInvalidParameterQuoteLeft() {
        parseAndSet("'${Invalid Parameter}");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testParserInvalidParameterQuoteRight() {
        parseAndSet("${Invalid Parameter}'");
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testParserInvalidParameterSpaces() {
        parseAndSet(" ${Invalid Parameter}");
    }

    @Test
    public void testParserValidStrings() {
        // Initialization condition.
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Null string.
        parseAndSet(null);
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Empty string.
        parseAndSet(new String());
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Single parameter.
        parseAndSet("... ${_A_}, $yada yada'$[]' '${");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("_A_");

        // Many parameters and one literal.
        parseAndSet("... ${_A_}, ${12345}, '${Literal}''${Non_Literal_Left} ${Non_Literal_Right}' ");
        assertResultSizes(4, 1);
        assertParamsContains("_A_");
        assertParamsContains("12345");
        assertParamsContains("Non_Literal_Left");
        assertParamsContains("Non_Literal_Right");
        assertLiteralsContains("Literal");

        // Nested literal and odd bracket placements.
        parseAndSet("''${Totally}''$}{$'${Single}");
        assertResultSizes(1, 1);
        assertParamsContains("Single");
        assertLiteralsContains("Totally");

        // Subset of ASCII characters.
        parseAndSet("`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?");
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Illegal characters in literal.
        parseAndSet("'${This literal is completely valid}'");
        assertResultSizes(0, 1);
        assertLiteralsContains("This literal is completely valid");

        // Test incomplete literal, no closure.
        parseAndSet("'${This literal is never closed");
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Test incomplete parameter from left.
        parseAndSet("${Never_Closed");
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // And again... with a parameter at the end.
        parseAndSet("${Never_Closed${But_This_Is}");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("But_This_Is");

        // Empty parameter.
        parseAndSet("${}");
        assertResultSizes(0, 0);

        // Restarting a new parameter within an already open parameter.
        parseAndSet("${Perfectly valid${a}");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("a");

        // Variation of the above with quotes.
        parseAndSet("'${Perfectly valid'${a}");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("a");

        // Variation of the above with quotes.
        parseAndSet("${Perfectly valid'${a}");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("a");

        // Variation of the above with quotes.
        parseAndSet("${Perfectly valid${a}'");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("a");

        // Variation of the above with quotes.
        parseAndSet("${Perfectly valid'${a}'");
        assertResultSizes(0, 1);
        assertLiteralsContains("a");

        // Variation of the above with spaces.
        parseAndSet(" ${ Perfectly valid${a} ");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("a");

        // TODO Determine what the desired behavior is for nested literals and parameters.

        // Test nested parameter in literal.
        parseAndSet("'${Nested ${Parameter}}'");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("Parameter");

        // Nested parameter.
        parseAndSet("${Nested_${Parameter}}'");
        assertResultSizes(1, 0);
        assertParamsContains("Parameter");

        // Literal nested in a parameter.
        parseAndSet(" ${Nested'${Literal}'}");
        assertResultSizes(0, 1);
        assertLiteralsContains("Literal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a negative lookbehind:

```
"(?<!')\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}"
```

This will now only match if the `$` is not preceded by `'`.

As Matt Ball mentioned in a comment, it might make sense to add another negative lookahead to the end, too:

```
"(?<!')\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}(?!')"
```

However, this will only matter if you have invalid/unmatched usage of `'` as in `${Literal}'` (in this case my first regex will still match `Literal`, the latter won't).

Comment: Looks good, but I'd add a negative lookahead for `'` as well.

Comment: @MattBall updated my answer and added some explanation for the addition

Comment: I'm confused -- the 2nd one doesn't seem to be matching.

I need ${Non_Literal}' to match because it won't be treated as a literal unless it has both single quotes around the braces.  Edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @MattBall Yeah, I'll probably do that.  Anyway, thanks, Buettner.  Good to know about negative lookbehind and lookforward.